# Cannot build or serve Jekyll site on OSX

Tags: ruby, macos, jekyll

I am running OS X 10.11.6 and I installed Jekyll (using the already existent ruby on my system) by the recommended method: `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin/ jekyll`.

I can happily run `jekyll` on my system so I made a new site by running `jekyll new TestSite` which successfully executed.

However, this is where it stops working: if I `cd` into the site directory and run any `jekyll` command I get the following error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:34:in `require_from_bundler'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/exe/jekyll:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas how to get it working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you don't have `bundler` gem. Try

`gem install bundler`

Comment: That does it. I still needed to also run `bundler install` as well. I would've imagined all the Jekyll dependencies would've been installed with it...